# Rails: Run callback only for CRUD operation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm in Rails 3. Here's my code for a method which creates Update records in response to certain attributes being changed on a model called Candidate:

```
before_save :check_changed, on: [:update]
def check_changed
  tracked_attributes = ["period_contributions", "total_contributions",
                        "period_expenditures", "total_expenditures",
                        "debts_and_loans", "cash_on_hand",
                        "major_endorsements",
                        "rating_afl_cio",
                        "rating_cal_tax",
                        "rating_cc",
                        "rating_eqca",
                        "rating_lcv",
                        "rating_now"]
  changes.each do |key, value|
    if tracked_attributes.include?(key)
      Update.create(:candidate_id => self.id, :attribute_name => key, 
    :new_value => value[1], :old_value => value[0])
    end
  end
end
```

The issue is that I have some rake tasks I'm running to do batch updates to the data, which end up triggering this callback unintentionally. I'd like for it only to run when a Candidate is updated from within the admin tool aka CRUD interface. Any advice on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will only use callbacks when it is something that always needs to happen, no matter the source. Magically skipping or including them normally leads to pain down the road.

My suggestion is to create a different method on the model that does the check and use that for the crud actions.

```
class Candidate
  #...

  def check_changed_and_update(attributes)
    check_changed
    update(attributes)
  end

  private

  def check_changed
    tracked_attributes = ["period_contributions", "total_contributions",
                          "period_expenditures", "total_expenditures",
                          "debts_and_loans", "cash_on_hand",
                          "major_endorsements",
                          "rating_afl_cio",
                          "rating_cal_tax",
                          "rating_cc",
                          "rating_eqca",
                          "rating_lcv",
                          "rating_now"]
    changes.each do |key, value|
      if tracked_attributes.include?(key)
        Update.create(:candidate_id => self.id, :attribute_name => key,
                      :new_value => value[1], :old_value => value[0])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in the controller for candidate just change `update` to `check_changed_and_update`:

```
class CanidateController < ApplicationController
  def update
    #...
    respond_to do |format|
      if @candidate.check_changed_and_update(canidate_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @candidate, notice: 'Candidate was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end
```

This has an added bonus of making it obvious what is going to happen when update is called.

Now you can just use the normal active record api in your rake tasks.